# Combine pockets of two multidimensional arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays that have a structure given below.

I need to combine the values of two arrays into one and the order should be in sequence. I need to keep the other pockets too.

The header should be first then the child and then the next header then the next child's pockets.

```
const header = {
    "list": [{
      "name": "header-a",
      "id": "id-a"
    }, {
      "name": "header-b",
      "id": "id-b"
    }]
  };
  const child = {
    "list": [{
      "name": "child",
      "id": "c1",
      'type': "id-a"
    },
      {
        "name": "child 2",
        "id": "c2",
        'type': "id-a"
      },
      {
        "name": "child 4",
        "id": "c4",
        'type': "id-b"
      },
      {
        "name": "child-5",
        "id": "c5",
        'type': "id-b"
      }]
  };
```

expected result is

```
  const result = {
    "list": [{
      "name": "header-a",
      "header": true,
    },
      {
        "name": "child",
        "id": "c1",
        'type': "id-a"
      },
      {
        "name": "child 2",
        "id": "c2",
        'type': "id-a"
      },
      {
        "name": "header-b",
        "header": true,
      },
      {
        "name": "child 4",
        "id": "c4",
        'type': "id-b"
      },
      {
        "name": "child-5",
        "id": "c5",
        'type': "id-b"
      }]
  };
```

Comment: Can you add expected result in your question ?

Comment: @Zurez already there.

Answer (score 0):

You loop through the headers and for each header, you push into the "combined" array an item like `{ name: header.name, header: true }`, then filter all children whose `type` is equal to the header `id` and push them too into the array:

```js
const header = {
  "list": [{
    "name": "header-a",
    "id": "id-a"
  }, {
    "name": "header-b",
    "id": "id-b"
  }]
};

const child = {
  "list": [{
      "name": "child",
      "id": "c1",
      'type': "id-a"
    },
    {
      "name": "child 2",
      "id": "c2",
      'type': "id-a"
    },
    {
      "name": "child 4",
      "id": "c4",
      'type': "id-b"
    },
    {
      "name": "child-5",
      "id": "c5",
      'type': "id-b"
    }
  ]
};

const combined = { list: [] };
header.list.forEach(h => {
  combined.list.push({ name: h.name, header: true });
  child.list.filter(c => c.type === h.id).forEach(c => combined.list.push(c));
});

console.log(combined);
```